# Is "believe each other" grammatically correct?

Tags: prepositions, idioms

I've often heard "believe in each other" used, but considering that "believe" is a transitive verb, it would seem to be grammatically correct to say "We have to believe each other", instead of saying "We have to believe in each other." Is this wording grammatically correct? Or is it not acceptable enough to use?

If it is grammatically correct, do both sentences convey the same meaning?

Comment: The phrasal verb [**believe in**](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/believe-in) is defined in most dictionaries. Which one did you consult? After looking at the definitions of the verbs _believe_ and _believe in,_ do you think they have the same meaning?

Comment: Although I think there is a difference in the meaning between "believe" and "believe in",(my dictionary is ODE, by the way) a native speaker of English judged the two wordings as correct, both of which have the same meaning as "trust each other,"  So I just wanted to make sure whether they share the meaning, as English is not my native language.

Comment: Your native speaker is in error, unfortunately. To be clear: _"We have to believe each other"_ is **not** identical in meaning to _"We have to believe **in** each other"_. The latter does not mean precisely "We must trust each other". Instead, it means ""We must have faith in each other". The difference is subtle but significant. Study example sentences in _multiple dictionaries_ to grasp this. (Try the [**OneLook**](http://www.onelook.com/?w=believe+in&ls=a&loc=home_ac_believe+in) dictionary to simplify your task.)

Comment: @P.E.Dant - +1, but a little more precisely: "We believe each other" means that each of us credits the other's veracity, while "We believe in each other" means that each of us reposes some *other* sort of faith in the other: faith that the other will succeed or prevail, for instance, or faith that the other will deal honestly with us, or faith that the other will support us in our endeavours.

Comment: That is what I've wanted to hear.  Relieved that I've learned so far is correct.  I really understand what you pointed out and couldn't agree more. Thanks for giving me the link to such a useful dictionary. I'll make use of it.

Answer (score 1):

On it's own, yes, it's correct. **But** it **doesn't** have the same meaning as "believe in". Instead it is synonymous with *we trust each other*.

Therefore, to answer your question, to convey your intended meaning, you must use the "in".

Comment: I see. It can be said "We have to believe each other", but it has a different meaning from "We have to believe in each other."  I'd like to use it correctly depending on context.

Comment: @maple1345 Precisely.